# Can new type classes be created in Linq-to-Objects?

Tags: linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects, variable-assignment

To create and assign classes on the fly from other objects I usually use LINQ.

Suppose I have a `IQueryable<ProductForCart>` object fetched from **my Database** and, for some reason, I need to create an `IQuaryable<Product>` where each `Product` properties are extracted from the `ProductForCart`.

I simply do:

```
IQueryable<ProductForCart> productsForCart = ProductRepository.GetProductsForCart();

IQueryable<Product> products = productsForCart.Select(sc => new Product
                                              {
                                                 ProdId = sc.ProdId,
                                                 ProdName = sc.ProdName,
                                                 //other properties
                                              }
```

This works smooth. But if I have `IList<ProductForCart>` and `IList<Product>` it throws a runtime exception:

*This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.*

I didn't know that LinqToObjects did not support this kind of assignments. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you use SqlFunctions in the _//other properties_ ?

Comment: yes because it was launching another exception with ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [SQLFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) or [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) in a Linq-to-Objects query.

You will need to replace those functions with an equivalent `.net` method